# Необходимо с помощью виджетов вывести на панель mate информацию о компьютере в alt linux

Tags: linux, altlinux, mate

Первый вариант, укороченный.
С помощью виджета "Команда".
Тогда вопрос, где находится файлы этого виджета? Имеется ввиду как мне включить через ssh или скрипт сам виджет на АРМах пользователя и прописать нужную команду для отображения.

[image: Вариант 1]

Второй вариант, более полный.
С помощью виджета "Обо мне".
В идеале отобразить выполнение команд "hostname -s" "whoami" "uptime -s" при наведении на значок, либо отобразить нужную информацию при клике на нем в самой панели "Обо мне", например под строкой имя пользователя, как видно на скриншоте. Ну и вопрос как в первом, где найти конфигурационные файлы, чтобы включить виджет у пользователя с нужными настройками.

[image: Второй вариант]